# Comparison between signed and unsigned

Tags: c, comparison, unsigned-char

```
int main(){
    char *mem = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        mem[i] = 0xFF;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(mem[i] == 0xFF){
            printf("True\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't print out True. However, when mem is declared as unsigned char, True is printed. How does comparision take place? I thought that == compares bit values, so why does it matter if it is char/unsigned char?

Comment: I can't seem to find a good duplicate written for C so I've linked a couple of C++ questions that have relevant answers.

Comment: "compares bit values" --> yes.When `char` is _signed_ with a value of -1 promoted to `int`:   0b11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 != 0b00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111. -1 != 255.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The [C wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) got a bunch of useful canonical dupes below FAQ, including [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default). I added it to the duplicate list.